# How do I display a html file with an image, from a servlet?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I want to display a html file from my servlet, the html file is stored in a different server than my webapp, I'm currently using the FileInputStream and ServletOutputStream classes to make it work, the problem is that it doesn't display the image. 
This is the code of my servlet:

```
public class DisplayImage extends HttpServlet {

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    ServletOutputStream out;
    out = response.getOutputStream();
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("C:\\Sistemas\\tendBe.html");

    BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
    BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(out);
    int ch = 0;;
    while ((ch = bin.read()) != -1) {
        bout.write(ch);
    }

    bin.close();
    fin.close();
    bout.close();
    out.close();       

//This doesn't work, it doesn't take that path.
   // RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("file://C://Sistemas//tendBe.html");

    //view.forward(request, response);

}}
```

And this is my html file:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Grafico</title>
    </head>
    <body>

       <h2 style='background-color:Lightgray;'><center>Tendencia    Beetle</center>       </h2>
       <div align='center'><b>Fecha: 25/06/2015<br>
       Status: 21:25</b></div>
       <center><b> 75</b></div><center>
       <br>
       <Left><img src='tendBe.png'><Left>
       <Left><img src='file:\\C:\\Sistemas\\tendBe.png'><Left>
    </body>
</html>
```

As a result, it does displays the html page, but the image is lost, somehow. I think that maybe is because the setContentType in which I specify text and I'm sending also an image?
Do you have any suggestions?
Also, the part using the getRequestDispatcher, gets me in trouble because it won't accept a specific path, and I don't think I will be putting the files in the application folder. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is since you don't have the files in your web app folder. The html generated still points to image at location `file:\\C:\\Sistemas\\tendBe.png` at server, which is certainly not accessible for the client.

As of now my suggestion is to create another servlet to read the image like you did for the html. Also update the image src in the html to the new image servlet url.

Or you may convert the image to base64 string, `data url` and use it as the image src in the html page. By this you can skip the need of creating new image servlet. There are several online tools to convert image [like](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.base64-image.de%2F&ei=ETuSVaSDPNC6uASR2oKgCw&usg=AFQjCNEqn844Zq6zkCBgxFc4fVPwKHWO7w&sig2=_RmS5G7T2wsbm0GPOngWEw&bvm=bv.96783405,d.c2E&cad=rja).

```html
Using data url
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot">
```

Comment: Thank you! You're right, my html was still pointing to a local address, I  changed it for the server's address and it's now working. I didn't have to change anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the `src` attribute of the `img` tags in your HTML, to provide a proper URL of the images. And you have to find a way to serve these images from the server.

Hint: Images are (usually) served with a separate request, i.e. browser makes a request to fetch the HTML, then analyses the HTML, and if it finds elements, that need to be downloaded (such as images, or CSS/Javascript files), the browser makes a new request to fetch them (one request per element).